# Windows Phone Map Won't Center

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I am attempting to just set a center point on a map and zoom in. Easy Right?

Nay....

```
  XAML
  <maps:Map x:Name="map" Height="689"/>

  C#
  map.Center = new GeoCoordinate() { Latitude = 41.8500300, Longitude = -87.6500500 };
  map.ZoomLevel = 15;
```

`ID_CAP_LOCATION` & `ID_CAP_MAP` enabled

Yet here is the run result

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After working with a Nokia Ambasador (Atley Hunter) I was able to come up with the solution.

After you set your map position you need to call the `UpdateLayout()` function

C#

```
  map.Center = new GeoCoordinate() { Latitude = 41.8500300, Longitude = -87.6500500 };
  map.ZoomLevel = 15;
  map.UpdateLayout();
```